# Can "extremely professional" have a negative connotation?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, ambiguity, connotation

If someone is described as *extremely professional*, might there be a negative side to it?

This is how I would take it in many contexts, and I'm wondering whether it's justified. If some chap at work were described as *extremely professional*, I would think to myself:

> I can certainly rely on him to do what he's asked in an efficient manner, and if he's processing my paperwork, I can be confident he's not going to lose it or file it in the wrong drawer. **But he's unlikely to be asking me if I want to come round for Christmas dinner.**

In other words, one consequence of his being extremely professional is that he is *only* professional and disinclined to have fun with his colleagues.

Is this a fair understanding of the term?

And what if we drop the word *extremely*? I think I would sometimes still take this line even then.

Comment: With a term like this, the connotations will vary considerably with the context in which it is used. For this reason, I think it would be unwise to read too much into it when no additional information is available or forthcoming.

Comment: The answer depends very much on context: What is the context in which the phrase was used, and how many scare quotes were used around the words "extremely" and "professional"?

Comment: "unlikely to be asking me if ..." but **no** none of *extremely, professional* or *extremely professional* bring in such a connotation in any way. Any such impression is an impression gained from individual past experience I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> might there be a negative side to it?

Yes, but the emphasis is on *might*.

On its own, given that the context is after all a professional one, "extremely professional" should probably be taken as positive unless other information (whether explicit or just tone of voice) gave a reason to interpret it in the "only professional" manner you mention.

Without such information it doesn't rule out the subject being very gregarious when off the clock.

It doesn't even say much about their cordiality while working, since both a brusque attitude and a very polite one could be described, for different reasons, as "extremely professional".

Really, the only thing you can interpret from this alone, is what is being said about how well they work.